# Twig: Looping a specific array

Tags: twig

I’ve been looking over this piece of code for over 3 days now, but can’t find the clue. I work with Twig but it probably is solvable for folks who know how to work with other PHP tools. I’m not the greatest coder so here it is:

I made two blogs:

- Blogs/news
- Blogs/team

Now I want to show only the articles of the team blog on my Index.html page. As shown below:

*Index.html*

```
{% if shop.blogs.team %}
  {% include 'snippets/team.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

But whatever I try, it shows either the blog articles from the news blog or articles from both the news and the team blog:

*Snippets/team.html*

```html
<div class="socialbar-blog">
  <div class="socialbar-blog-box">                
    {% for blog in shop.blogs | limit(2) %} 
      {# this says how many articles in the categorie blog must been shown #}
      {% for article in blog.articles | limit(3) %} 
        <div class="blog-article">
          <h3 class="aligncenter"><a href="{{ article.url | url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></h3>
          <p class="aligncenter">{{ article.summary }}</p>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Solutions I’ve tried but didn’t work:

1. `{% for blog in shop.blogs | limit(team) %}`
2. `{% for blog in shop.blogs.team.title | limit(1) %}`
3. `{% include 'snippets/team.rain' with {'articles': team} %}`
4. `{% include 'snippets/team.rain' with {'title': 'team'} %}`

If I use the limit 1 in `{% for blog in shop.blogs | limit(2) %}` it only shows the News blog which is the first blog. How can I select the second array? Or is there another solution for this? (f.e. with if/else system)

Comment: Could you showe me the results of `{{ dump(shop.blogs) }}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for my question. Now the snippet only shows the articles from the Team blog.

```
{% for blog in shop.blogs %}
  {% if blog.title == 'team' %}
{% for article in blog.articles | limit(3) %}

<div class="blog-article">
<h3 class="aligncenter"><a href="{{ article.url | url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></h3>
<p class="aligncenter">{{ article.summary }}</p>
</div>

{% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```